# structure of the front-end application

Tags: node.js, angular

I write applications for my internal use.
I have one frontend as an information page where there is an option to log in to the platform.

The second frontend is the dashboard that appears after the user logs in on the first page.

Everything is handled by one backend.

Is it good practice to have two separate frontends?
Should I have everything in one frontend?

The stack is simple Nodejs, Angular, MySQL
Now I am working on redirecting users from one frontend to second.
Trying use httpCookie.

is it a good practice to have a separate frontend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my ten years of experience, I would recommend using a single front-end if your application is simple. Overcomplicating the process can lead to unnecessary issues.

When dealing with multiple functionalities that are not closely related to each other, it is best to use micro-frontends, similar to microservices.

You can read [https://www.rst.software/blog/micro-frontend-architecture-101-what-is-it-when-to-use-it-and-how-to-migrate-your-existing-monolithic-app-in-9-steps#:~:text=Micro%20frontends%20work%20very%20well,frontends%20are%20your%20best%20option](https://www.rst.software/blog/micro-frontend-architecture-101-what-is-it-when-to-use-it-and-how-to-migrate-your-existing-monolithic-app-in-9-steps#:%7E:text=Micro%20frontends%20work%20very%20well,frontends%20are%20your%20best%20option).

Answer (score 1):

In a project I worked on we did this. The first frontend was used to add new information. The second one to create users and assign to them the date they will have access to. And it goes on. Frontends were separated based on workflow.

I don't see any particular problems with it, aside from the fact that you'd need to create, deploy and maintain multiple separate frontend projects.
If it makes sense to separate the app, by all means you can do it. Just make sure it doesn't complicate things for no reason.

If the application was not for internal use and would have to be crawled for SEO purposes, maybe that could make things tricky.